# How do I enable 3d effects on a Sony Vaio E Series?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, 3d, effects

I have a sony Vaio E series Laptop [VPCEB24EN] with ATI Radeon Graphic card. I have installed ubuntu 11.10 and tried to activate the compiz effects. I am not able to activate the special effects [3D effects], and when i restarted my system i am not able to start any applications and i re-installed ubuntu. In the previous version [11.04] also i was facing the same issue. But in Ubuntu 10.10, all the compiz effects are working properly for me. Please help.

Comment: What ATI card? ther's TONS of models...also are you still on 11.10?

Comment: @Prajith Which particular effects are you trying to enable? Unity doesn't always play nicely with other Compiz effects, the Desktop Cube being the first that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

11.10 and 11.04 have Unity by default. 
10.10 however does not.

In 11.10 and 11.04
You can use the gnome fallback and enjoy the compiz settings as you wish. This is how:

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

When you log out and back in choose Gnome-Classic

Installing CompizConfig Settings Manager

The utility to use and configure Compiz is the CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm). Download it by opening a terminal and entering the following:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

[tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/enabling-compiz-fusion-on-ubuntu-11.10-oneiric-ocelot)